# Azure Cloud Services - Turn on PHP Display Errors

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-roles

I am unable to turn on display_errors in my Azure WebRole. I have tried editing the php.ini on the WebRole, and adding my own php.ini file to the .cspkg file before deployment. But still no errors display on screen.

Could someone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried typing `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your PHP file

Comment: Yes I have `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);` but it is in a config.php which is included from an init.php, which is included in the index.php. So I don't know if it is getting that far. It's a very large app.

Comment: Try too add `error_reporting(-1)` on the page where you want to see the error. Like you said it might be possible that it doesn't get that far.

Comment: OK I just added `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);` to the very top of the index.php file and there is still no output, no errors or anything

Comment: @AzaZPPL Nope still nothing...

Comment: I'm sorry this goes beyond my knowledge.

Comment: OK I added `error_reporting(-1)` to the top and then only added a echo statement. This worked. I then removed the semi-colon from the end of `error_reporting(-1)` and it displayed the error correctly. when I put the `init.php` include back in, I get a blank page again. Obviously something is not working, but why no error?